# How do you set up a page to use a different template in Zotonic?

Tags: zotonic

I would like to have alternative templates for each section of my website.

How do you set up a page to use a different template in Zotonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could render the about page with a custom template:

```
{about,      ["about"], resource_page, [ {template, "about.tpl"}, {id, page_about}]}
```

If you add the above dispatch rule to your site's dispatch rules (found at yoursite/dispatch/dispatch) it will render a page with the unique name of page_about using about.tpl.

You can set the unique name for a page in the advanced tab of the page in the zotonic admin.

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is to set the `page_path` property to the url you define in the dispatch rule.  So that the page_url of the (in the example) page_about is also "/about".